# Working with SVG polygon defined by user

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, snap.svg

i want to take the number of polygon's sides and makes the polygon accordingly.
Is there any way through which i can take the number of polygon's sides and make a SVG polygon depending on that.
Any way i can do this way ??

Comment: do you mean something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polygon ?

Comment: these are the defined point. i have to ask the user no of sides he/she wants in it ? and then make a polygon accordingly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function makePolygon(posX, posY, numSides, size)
{
  var points = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < numSides; i++) {
    points.push(posX + size * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / numSides));
    points.push(posY + size * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * i / numSides));
  }

  // Create a polygon element
  var poly = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "polygon");
  poly.setAttribute("points", points.join(','));
  
  // Add it to the SVG
  document.getElementById("mysvg").appendChild(poly);
}


makePolygon(250,250, 9, 200);
```

```css
polygon {
  fill: yellow;
  stroke: blue;
  stroke-width: 10;
}
```

```html
<svg id="mysvg" width="500" height="500"></svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create svg polygons using the svg `polygon` element, all you need to calculate are the vertices of your polygon. Assuming you want to create a regular polygon (otherwise there is an unlimited amount of polygons with `n` sides, the vertices can be calculated as:

```
var vertices = [];
for(var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    vertices.push({
       x : Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / n),
       y : Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * i / n)
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you meant: (2 * Math.PI * i / n)